# enable a script to stop itself when a command is issued from terminal

Tags: python, linux

I have a script `runReports.py` that is executed every night. Suppose for some reason the script takes too long to execute, I want to be able to stop it from terminal by issuing a command like `./runReports.py stop`.

I tried to implement this by having the script to create a temporary file when the stop command is issued.

The script checks for existence of this file before running each report.

If the file is there the script stops executing, else it continues.

But I am not able to find a way to make the issuer of the stop command aware that the script has stopped successfully. Something along the following lines:

```
$ ./runReports.py stop
  Stopping runReports...
  runReports.py stopped successfully.
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your script runnIng? What facilities does it have to write to the invoking user's terminal or GUI? Probably the easiest is for the closer to open a pipe for reading and wait for the main script to write its status to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve inter process communication. You should first explore the different ways to do that : system V IPC (memory, very versatile, possibly baffling API), sockets (including unix domain sockets)(memory, more limited, clean API), file system (persistent on disk, almost architecture independent), and choose yours.

As you are asking about files, there are still two ways to communicate using files : either using file content (feature rich, harder to implement), or simply file presence. But the problem using files, is that is a program terminates because of an error, it may not be able to write its ended status on the disk.

IMHO, you should clearly define what are your requirements before choosing file system based communication (testing the end of a program is not really what it is best at) unless you also need architecture independence.

To directly answer your question, the only reliable way to know if a program has ended if you use file system communication is to browse the list of currently active processes, and the simplest way is IMHO to use `ps -e` in a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

For example if your script runs in loop, you can catch signal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal and terminate process:

```
import signal

class SimpleReport(BaseReport):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        is_running = True

    def _signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
        is_running = False

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self._signal_handler) # set signal handler
        ...
        while is_running:
            print("Preparing report")
        print("Exiting ...")
```

To terminate process just call kill -SIGUSR1 procId

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a temporary file, you could have a permanent file(config.txt) that has some tags in it and check if the tag 'running = True'.

To achieve this is quiet simple, if your code has a loop in it (I imagine it does), just make a function/method that branches a check condition on this file.

```
def continue_running():
    with open("config.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            tag, condition = line.split(" = ")
            if tag == "running" and condition == "True":
                return True
    return False
```

In your script you will do this:

```
while True: # or your terminal condition
    if continue_running():
        # your regular code goes here
    else:
        break
```

So all you have to do to stop the loop in the script is change the 'running' to anything but "True".